# max defined in #define not working properly

Tags: c++, c

I wrote the program as follows :

```
#include<cstdio>
#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum=0,i,k;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
      sum=sum+max(i,3);
    }
    printf("%d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

> I got the  output : 4

But when I stored `max(i,3`) in a variable `k` and then added to `sum`, I got the correct output:

```
#include<cstdio>
#define max(a,b) a>b?a:b
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int sum=0,i,k;
   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
     k=max(i,3);
     sum=sum+k;
   }
   printf("%d\n",sum);
   return 0;
}
```

> Output : 16

Can somebody please explain why is it happening?

Comment: always use parens in defining macro's that take arguments ((a>b) ? a : b)

Comment: Because it's a macro.

Comment: @BsD, And this is the exact reason macros should be avoided if possible. Your correction is still missing parentheses: `((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))`

Comment: If you're going to tag a question as C, make the code valid C.

Comment: If it's indeed C++, despite the C tag, use `std::max`.

Answer (score 5):

hash-define macros are a string expansion, not a "language" thing.

```
sum=sum+max(i,3);
```

expands to:

```
sum=sum+i>3?i:3;
```

And if you are writing that with no () round it you deserve to get the wrong answer.  Try this:

```
#define max(a,b) (a>b?a:b)
```

but there are still **many** situations where it will fail.  As others point out an even better macro is:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

but it will **still** fail in too many situations, such as arguments with side effects getting evaluated twice.  You are much much better off avoiding macros where possible and doing something like this:

```
template <typename T> T max(T a, T b) { return a>b?a:b; }
```

or, infact, using std::max and std::min which have already been written for you!

Comment: Your macro can easily be broken by valid arguments. Switch the commented line to compare: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69619687946a13f3

Comment: Yes, or just by using the ++ operator in one of the arguments, which is the classic way to break macros.  I did say there are situations where it will fail.  Edited and added "many" :p

Comment: Yes, but ++ happening twice on arguments used twice can't easily be avoided, whereas this one can, via extra parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
sum=sum+max(i,3);
```

expands to:

```
sum = sum + i > 3 ? i : 3;
```

Which, when set up with parens to make it clearer is:

```
sum = (sum + i) > 3 ? i : 3;
```

So on the 5-passes through the loop, the expressions are:

```
sum = (0 + 0) > 3 ? 0 : 3;  // Result, sum = 3
sum = (3 + 1) > 3 ? 1 : 3;  // Result: sum = 3
sum = (3 + 2) > 3 ? 2 : 3;  // Result: sum = 3
sum = (3 + 3) > 3 ? 3 : 3;  // Result: sum = 3
sum = (3 + 4) > 3 ? 4 : 3;  // Result: sum = 4
```

And that's where your answer comes from.

The conventional way to solve this is to change the `#define` to:

```
 #define max(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
```

But even this has some pitfalls.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are having operator precedence issues, you have to remember that define will lead to a textual replacement in your source code. You should change your define to

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of the prepocessor (view it with the `-E` flag) will be:

```
sum = sum+i>3?i:3;
```

which is the same as

```
sum = (sum+i)>3?i:3;
```

which is not what you meant because `+` has a *higher* precedence than `>`. You should use:

```
#define max(a,b) (a>b?a:b)
```

instead.

Comment: Your macro can easily be broken by valid arguments. Switch the commented line to compare: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69619687946a13f3

Answer (score 1):

Replacing your macro in the line `sum=sum+max(i,3);` gives the following form :

```
sum=sum+i>3?i:3 ;
```

which is asking that if `sum + i` is greater than `3` than assign sum's value accordingly. Hence, you have 4 because each time a new assignment happens inside the loop. Use the template method suggested by Andrew.

(The loop evaluates the condition `(sum + i) > 3 ? i : 3` every time. There is no cumulative addition here.)